# Remove special character of substring only by Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

```
<html lang="en">
  ;;;;;;
  <body>
    <script>
      var a = 3;
      var b = a * 10;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is is content of a string variable of my project.
And I want to remove `;` of javascript code, not remove `;` above the `<body>`
Only remove `;` between `<script>` and `</script>`
Is it possible by Regular Expression?

The purpose to do this is that I want to remove unnecessary characters of string, and the string can include javascript and other language.
But as you know javascript allow semicolons and no-semicolons.

Comment: specify language

Comment: sorry, I am using javascript for this project

Comment: Blindly removing every `;` will break JavaScript code.

Comment: Actually, the code string what I want to remove characters is for compare with other string.

Comment: Please _don't_ attempt to parse HTML using regex, certainly not nested content as you seem to have here.  Regex + HTML = generally evil ^ ^

Comment: `Actually, the code what I want to remove characters is for compare with other string.` then remove during the compare, not from the actual string

Comment: The string can include solidity, javascript, .... not only html and javascript.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney So my question is that how to remove it by Regex.
Is it impossible by Regex?

Comment: Yes, it's possible - Google `javascript remove characters regex`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Remove special characters between <script> and </script>, not remove all special characters. There is `;;;;;` above <body>, but it's example. The string can include other `;` out of `<script></script>`

Comment: as already said, regexp is the wrong tool here. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 . However, if "being after the exact `<body>` string" in your html file is your only requirement, you can use a lookbehind. But it won't work properly if for instance you have litteral text `<body>` somewhere in a script before the HTML tag `<body>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

You can try **Regex lookbehind**. [Working example](https://jsbin.com/pidosir/2/edit?js,console)

**Problem** - Less Browser support

## Long answer

You can use **Regex capturing group** to search for the semicolon which needs to be removed using the following pattern:

`/(<script>[\S\s]*);(?=[\s\S]*<\/script>)/g`

And then, you can use `String.replace()` method to remove the semicolon. [Working example](https://jsbin.com/laniwuz/1/edit?js,console)